# tomcat starts but doesnt show up in browser when entering: localhost:8080 or ip:8080 Centos7 vm

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, centos7

so I've manually installed tomcat version 9.0.10 and the newest java JDK. 
I've correctly added the manager-gui and admin-gui users. i have went into the server.xml files and found that all the ports were correct.. (connecting to default port 8080) I had to do   []# unset CATALINA_HOME   or else it wouldn't let me start tomcat so I did and it started but when I went to the browser and typed in the localhost:8080 it didn't show, it only says firefox could not establish connection with server localhost:8080 so I went into logs to see if there were any errors and sure enough there was an error like so: /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/bin/catalina.sh: line 464: /usr/bin/Java/jdk-10.0.2/bin/bin/java does not exist.. and its probably right why would there be /bin/bin/ like that in a directory.. so i went into the catalina.sh file copied what it had inside into a blank file in documents and went to line 464 (txt editor numbered the lines for me) and what i found was this line at 464: eval $_NOHUP "\"$_RUNJAVA" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS %CATALINA_OPTS\

but I have no idea what to do about it.. i think i might have a path problem or could be a port problem but I don't think so... I've installed apache and it works great in the browser with localhost.. could that affect the tomcat access maybe?

anyway, id really appreciate any help I can get.. I'm very new to this by the way. I'm sorry, I couldn't copy and paste from my virtual machine so I had to type it. im on centos 7.

Comment: Can you paste your catalina.sh file

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for tomcat deployment page where you can manage your artifact. If that is correct
First thing you need to check is that whether your installation contains tomcat manager application.
You can verify this by looking in to this path ("apache-tomcat-9.0.10\webapps\manager") If this path is absent you may have to reinstall your tomcat.

Try downloading the zip from the below path and start the server.

If you are trying to deploy your custom application you may have to provide the context path for accessing you application. Also you can verify the deployment by looking in to the above path. For eg: if you are trying to deploy test.war then a folder named test will appear in the webapp folder.
Hope this helps.

Comment: yes my installation does contain the tomcat manager application. I checked the way you told me to and they exist. I am trying to reach the welcome page where it has the cat and a green message which says "if youre reading this, you've successfully installed tomcat, congratulations". that is the only page im trying to reach for now.. thank you for responding!